# How to add Windows explorer favorites on user logon

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have some Favorites links in Windows explorer (not IE). I am looking for a way to apply those favorites to administrator@mycompany.com account each time I log on to any PC in our company.

I have a login.vbs script based on PC name, not user name.

What is the best way to do this for admin account? I dont find too much options for favorites in windows explorer.

Comment: Do you mean items "pinned" to the Start menu (not in "All Programs")? If so then this is very difficult to achieve without scripting. Why? To prevent software installers from doing it and bloating your Start menu "pinned" area.

Comment: Check whether "Jack Douglas" answer matches your requirement. I understand that the admin profile should be treated similar like roaming profile and you would like to map the favorites where ever the admin logs in. http://serverfault.com/questions/457738/how-do-i-add-items-to-favorites-via-gpo

Comment: @big chris I mean favorites in Windows explorer.